# How to zoom coverflow images using pinch zoom in android

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, pinch

i have created a coverflow using the code given by http://android.jmsliu.com/138/android-infinite-loop-gallery.html. [image]

And it is working fine . Now my question is How i will implement a pinch zoom for the images .?

i have used the TouchImageView class instead of ImagView. but it is not working.

below given is the TouchImageView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

   public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;

float redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace;

float width, height;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
float right, bottom, origWidth, origHeight, bmWidth, bmHeight;

ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;


public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    matrix.setTranslate(1f, 1f);
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float scaleWidth = Math.round(origWidth * saveScale);
                        float scaleHeight = Math.round(origHeight * saveScale);
                        if (scaleWidth < width) {
                            deltaX = 0;
                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom); 
                        } else if (scaleHeight < height) {
                            deltaY = 0;
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);
                        } else {
                            if (x + deltaX > 0)
                                deltaX = -x;
                            else if (x + deltaX < -right)
                                deltaX = -(x + right);

                            if (y + deltaY > 0)
                                deltaY = -y;
                            else if (y + deltaY < -bottom)
                                deltaY = -(y + bottom);
                        }
                        matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) { 
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    bmWidth = bm.getWidth();
    bmHeight = bm.getHeight();
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x)
{
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = (float)Math.min(Math.max(.95f, detector.getScaleFactor()), 1.05);
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }
        right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
        bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
        if (origWidth * saveScale <= width || origHeight * saveScale <= height) {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, width / 2, height / 2);
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                matrix.getValues(m);
                float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
                if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                    if (Math.round(origWidth * saveScale) < width) {
                        if (y < -bottom)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                        else if (y > 0)
                            matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
                    } else {
                        if (x < -right) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                        else if (x > 0) 
                            matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float x = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float y = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
            if (mScaleFactor < 1) {
                if (x < -right) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-(x + right), 0);
                else if (x > 0) 
                    matrix.postTranslate(-x, 0);
                if (y < -bottom)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -(y + bottom));
                else if (y > 0)
                    matrix.postTranslate(0, -y);
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    //Fit to screen.
    float scale;
    float scaleX =  (float)width / (float)bmWidth;
    float scaleY = (float)height / (float)bmHeight;
    scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    saveScale = 1f;

    // Center the image
    redundantYSpace = (float)height - (scale * (float)bmHeight) ;
    redundantXSpace = (float)width - (scale * (float)bmWidth);
    redundantYSpace /= (float)2;
    redundantXSpace /= (float)2;

    matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

    origWidth = width - 2 * redundantXSpace;
    origHeight = height - 2 * redundantYSpace;
    right = width * saveScale - width - (2 * redundantXSpace * saveScale);
    bottom = height * saveScale - height - (2 * redundantYSpace * saveScale);
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
}
}
```

can anybody help me to sort this problem..

Thanks in advance

Here i am adding my class files .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class InfiniteGalleryActivity extends Activity {

public static int pos;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            InfiniteGallery gallery = (InfiniteGallery) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
            gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

            gallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {


                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                         Intent intent = new Intent(InfiniteGalleryActivity.this, TouchImageViewActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("postion", pos);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    return false;
                }


            });

    }
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

            private final Integer[] imageDataList = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b,
                            R.drawable.c};

            public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                    if (imageDataList != null) {
                            return imageDataList.length;
                    } else {
                            return 0;
                    }
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                    return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = convertView;
                    pos =position;
                    if (view == null) {
                            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemrender, parent, false);
                    }

                    ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(imageDataList[position]);
                    return view;
            }
    }
   }
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity {
Bitmap imageToBeZoom = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        int postion = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");

                    // Here you must add the resource id for image potion.
                    int resourse_id = postion;// get the resouce id here e.g arr[postion];
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourse_id);
        imageToBeZoom = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

        ZoomableImageView zoom = new ZoomableImageView(TouchImageViewActivity.this);
        zoom.setBitmap(imageToBeZoom);
        zoom.setHandler(handler);

        LayoutParams parms = new LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        LinearLayout layou = new LinearLayout(TouchImageViewActivity.this);
        layou.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        layou.addView(zoom, parms);
        setContentView(layou);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (imageToBeZoom != null && imageToBeZoom.isRecycled() == false) {
        imageToBeZoom.recycle();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Now i need to slide images in the gallery and zoom the current image that is there in the view .

Comment: Its tricky to be done this using gallery. As galley use the touch event for animation. So the touch event is not used by the image. What I have done is that use simple ImageView in gallery. But when user Mutitouch the gallery, then show user "TouchView" where user can make zoom.

Comment: Hi arslan .. thanks for the reply .. can you please shre your code with me ... it will be very helpful for my project .

Comment: It could be also possible to embedde all the image in the webview and then just use the implicitly defined zoom functions in the webview component. This could be an alternative solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class InfiniteGalleryActivity extends Activity {

    public static int pos;
    ImageAdapter adapter = null;
    InfiniteGallery gallery = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        gallery = (InfiniteGallery) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gallery.setAdapter(adapter);

        gallery.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

                    Intent intent = new Intent(InfiniteGalleryActivity.this, TouchImageViewActivity.class);
                    pos = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    int resId = adapter.getResId(pos);
                    intent.putExtra("resource_id", resId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                return false;
            }

        });

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        private final int[] imageDataList = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c };

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
                if (imageDataList != null) {
                return imageDataList.length;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public int getResId(int position) {
            return imageDataList[position];
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            pos = position;
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemrender, parent, false);
            }

            ((ImageView) view).setImageResource(imageDataList[position]);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class TouchImageViewActivity extends Activity {
Bitmap imageToBeZoom = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        int rid = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("resource_id");

        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), rid);
        imageToBeZoom = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);

        ZoomableImageView zoom = new ZoomableImageView(TouchImageViewActivity.this);
        zoom.setBitmap(imageToBeZoom);

        LayoutParams parms = new LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        LinearLayout layou = new LinearLayout(TouchImageViewActivity.this);
        layou.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.black);
        layou.addView(zoom, parms);
        setContentView(layou);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (imageToBeZoom != null && imageToBeZoom.isRecycled() == false) {
        imageToBeZoom.recycle();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Please ask here you are missing. I have no project to share. Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/a85/WebComicViewer/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/ui/ZoomableImageView.java

Comment: need some clarification for below variables . 1. what is this resourse_id, imagePath and the handler ?

Comment: hi Arslan ... i have edited my question. pls check it and help me to sort this problem ..

Comment: Hi guys .. finally i solved it with the help of this sample code https://github.com/alvinsj/android-image-gallery

Comment: @Kris: That's good if you find some solution. I have also update my answer on your request.

Comment: Hi  @Kris, i am struggling with the same problem. I have dropped question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706848/zoom-the-image-in-the-gallery) here .Please help me out

Comment: Hi @Arslan, i am expecting from u also to help me out.